# Iterating through data from a SOAP Response to store in an Excel Worksheet

Tags: web-services, loops, soap, xquery, soapui

I know that there is a DataLoop that can be used to iterate over elements in a DataSource, but how do I iterate over elements that I am extracting into a DataSink?

I have a SOAP Response containing 100 records and I need to extract different elements from each record and store the data in an Excel worksheet.  Currently I am extracting the data with a Property Transfer and using a DataSink to save it to a spreadsheet.  Below is an example of the code that takes the first author name in each record and transfers it to the DataSink (this is within the Source section of the Property Transfer window):

```
declare namespace ns2='http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com';
declare namespace ns1='http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord';

<full_name>
{
for $id in //ns1:name[1]//ns1:full_name[1]
return string($id)
}
</full_name>
```

However, this takes ALL the names from every record as a list and stores them in a single cell in the Excel worksheet (similarly for the other data fields I'm extracting).  How can I do the Property Transfer for the 1st record into the DataSink, then iterate back to do the Property Transfer for the 2nd record, and so on until I have iterated over all 100 records?

Thank you for your help!

John

- EDIT:

Here is an example of the XML Document I am trying to retrieve data from, I have taken out some elements as it is extremely long otherwise!:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <ns2:retrieveByIdResponse xmlns:ns2="http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com">
    <return>
        <queryId>2</queryId>
        <recordsFound>100</recordsFound>
        <recordsSearched>50601246</recordsSearched>
        <records><records xmlns="http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord">
            <REC r_id_disclaimer="ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters">    <UID>WOS:000266862400001</UID><static_data><summary><EWUID><WUID coll_id="WOS"></WUID><edition value="WOS.SCI"></edition><names count="3"><name seq_no="1" addr_no="1" role="author" reprint="Y"><display_name>Buijs, Arjen E.</display_name><full_name>Buijs, Arjen E.</full_name> ... etc ... </REC>
            <REC> ... etc ... </REC>
            <REC> ... etc ... </REC>
        </records></records>
     </return>
  </ns2:retrieveByIdResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

All the data I am extracting lies within these `<REC>` tags, so I am trying to extract fields like `<full_name>` from each `<REC>` and then pass it into an Excel spreadsheet.

I have managed to display the data exactly as I want it by using a DataSource step just after this SOAP Request/Response which extracts all the necessary fields by using the DataSource as XML and then referencing the XPath of each in the Row and Column sections.  When I click the green test button in this window, the Data Log displays all 100 records with a column for each field type.  When I try to pass all this data into a DataSink however, it only copies over the first row 100 times into the Excel worksheet.

Sorry, I would post a screenshot but you need reputation 10+ to do that!

- EDIT 2:

For example, for the field `<full_name>` I have made a property called `Author 1` in the DataSource, set to XML, Source Step is the SOAP Request and Source Property is the Response (the data listed in the code block above).  In the Row XPath I then have:

```
declare namespace ns2='http://woksearch.v3.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com';
declare namespace ns1='http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord';
//ns2:retrieveByIdResponse[1]/return[1]/records[1]/ns1:records[1]/ns1:REC
```

In the Column XPaths I have:

```
declare namespace ns1='http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord'; ns1:static_data/ns1:summary/ns1:names/ns1:name[1]/ns1:full_name/text()
```

When I run the test in this window, this displays a column with the header 'Author 1' and then lists 100 different names.  When I transfer this to a DataSink however, it only lists the first row 100 times in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will put all the first names into a single XML element called `full_name`. However I think you want to output them independently, but then all you would need is this:

```
declare namespace ns1 = 'http://scientific.thomsonreuters.com/schema/wok5.4/public/FullRecord';

//ns1:name[1]//ns1:full_name[1]
```

Comment: That will give me the 'full_name' of the author in the first record only though.  The XML Response I'm getting the data from has a full list of 100 records each with a unique 'full_name' and I want to iterate through all these records so that I can populate 100 cells in Excel with all the different author 'full_name' values.

Comment: I think you need to paste a small example of your data. But perhaps you want something like `//ns1:name//ns1:full_name[1]`

Comment: It's too long and so won't let me copy the exact code, here is a representation of the XML Response document I am transferring Properties from:

Comment: Ugh, that's really messy, sorry.  Don't know how to neaten it up, that isn't how I typed it in!  Anwyay `//ns1:name//ns1:full_name[1]` only returns me the first name from the data.  I've been trying loads of XPath solutions but they seem to only be able to return a single value.  The XQuery method will return many values but all in a single element.  I think I need to find a way to go from SOAP Response > Property Transfer > DataSink (Excel) for all the elements in the 1st record, then iterate back to the Property Transfer and go through the 2nd and so on, but can't figure out how.  Thanks!

Comment: The XML you pasted does not match your description as it does not have any `name` elements. Please can you remove that comment, and create a proper small example of the XML and edit your question with it. At the moment I cannot understand your problem enough

Comment: Okay, I've added some more to the comment above, let me know if it makes more sense now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow a sequence something like this:

1. SOAP call to retrieve your data.
2. DataSource with type = xml to grab all the records, one at a time.
3. DatasSink to write each one record to your Excel.
4. Loop back to #2 to iterate over all the records.